# I'am unable to populate the saved percent value in angular material mat select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm listing down 1-100 numbers using mat-form-field in mat-option . It is not showing the saved value in the dropdown after saving.**

```
<mat-form-field class="full-wid" appearance="outline">
                  <mat-label>Percentage 1 (%)</mat-label>
                  <mat-select matTooltip="Please percentage" class="numbers" [required]="percentTorF"
                    (selectionChange)="selected2()" [formControl]="salaryform.controls['Percentage1']"
                    [(ngModel)]="percentValue1">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let n1 of numbers1" [value]="n1">{{ n1 }}</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="salaryform.controls['Percentage1'].hasError('required')">
                    Percentage is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]**
[image]

Comment: What is the result of `{{percentValue1 | json }}`? plus show the sample data of `numbers1` array

Comment: it would be better if you can create a stackblitz for it.

Comment: public numbers1 = [];     for (let i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
          this.numbers1.push(i);
        }

Comment: Are you using Forms? Reactive?

Comment: Yes using reactive forms.

Comment: Then please porvide a stackblitz demo where I/we can reproduce the same issue!

Comment: see my json data Percentage1 is the form control name. percentValue1 is the ngModel

Comment: How you binding other values like bank name etc?

Comment: <mat-form-field class="full-wid" appearance="outline">
                      <input matInput placeholder="Account Holder Name"
                        [formControl]="salaryform.controls['AccountHolderName1']" required>
                      <mat-error
                        *ngIf="salaryform.controls['AccountHolderName1'].hasError('required') && salaryform.controls['AccountHolderName1'].touched">
                        Please enter account holder name
                      </mat-error>        
                    </mat-form-field>

Comment: I mean binding. By using ngModel or used formControl? to set the value?

Comment: Other values are binded using set value.

Comment: It will better if you provide stackblitz demo, there must be a minor mistake

Comment: okay give 10 mins I'll provide you stackblitz.

Comment: Can we connect through team viewer? Because using stackblitz i'am unable to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Convert percentage integer value to string using `toString()` before filling form values.

Comment: Can you tell me where I have to convert the percentage interger value?

Comment: When you fetch details to fill form:

Comment: `Edit(data){this.Form = this.fb.group({
      percentage:Data.percentage.toString()})}` something of this sort

Comment: If you're using formgroup, you can directly use only `formControlName` instead of `formControl` and `ngModel` combined. Also, make sure your fetched value is available in **numbers1** array.

Comment: Instead of `public numbers1 = []; for (let i = 1; i <= 99; i++) { this.numbers1.push(i); }` use `public numbers1 = Array(100).fill().map((e,i)=>i+1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding formControlName and Array(100).fill()

Comment: But still the percentage value is not populating, after saving it is visible. But as soon as when I refresh the page it is not showing the saved percent value.

Comment: Try removing `ngModel`.Only use `formControl` and try debugging what's th value there that doesn't get filled.